# Android Two-Way Data Binding Observer Called Twice

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-jetpack, two-way-binding, mutablelivedata

I am learning to use data binding from the following example:

https://github.com/ResoCoder/databinding-with-livedata-tutorial

In particular, I'm having trouble with the following code:

https://github.com/ResoCoder/databinding-with-livedata-tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/resocoder/databinding/MainActivity.kt

Line #29 has a Toast:

Toast.makeText(this, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

If the editTextContent is changed programmatically, the toast is called twice. You can reproduce this behavior by pressing the button labeled: "SELECT RANDOM FRUIT FROM EDITTEXT"

In this example, calling the observer twice is wasteful as it shows the toast twice, but in my application of the same feature it causes a serious problem for the user because I perform different actions if the data is changed programmatically vs the user.

I tried mitigating the problem by flagging the state as being a programmatic change, but the extraneous second call comes after my code is is completed. The call appears as if the user is editing the text so my program performs the action as if the user entered the data. I can't see any way to tell the difference between the extraneous call and the user entering the data.

Please don't suggest I stash away the value of the entry and if it didn't change, ignore the extraneous call. There is a legitimate use case where the user types exactly the same value back into the field.

Ideally finding the cause of the extraneous call and eliminating it would be best to both fix the problem and increase efficiency. Less desirable would be a workaround so I can ignore the second call so my code works correctly.

I suspect it has something to do with setting up an adapter or possibly when/where I set the observer, but that is a guess.

Thanks.

Comment: Reading between the lines from an Android Error report, extraneous observe calls is quite possible and may be fixed in a future release.

Comment: Hi Mitch, I'm facing the same issue. Where you able to find a solution or where can I find the Android Error report you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

- **Here is the result of how I did it**
- **GIF** is Powered by **imgur**

[image: Gif]
**==> How you can do it**

1. implement [core_android module](https://github.com/MohamedAlaaEldin636/MAUtils/wiki) of my library, surely not the whole library nor the module
   was just for that issue but it includes a solution to this issue as you see in the gif above.
2. in activity_main.xml

```xml
<!-- use the below 2 attributes
1st one ensures single trigger & 2nd one to distinguish the change -->
<EditText
    editText_textTwoWay="@={viewModel.mutableLiveDataEditTextContent}"
    editText_textTwoWay_enableDistinguishChangeCauser="@{true}"/>
```

3. in MainActivity.kt

```
// inside onCreate()

// for dynamic change -> on button click
button.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.mutableLiveDataEditTextContent.value = "Hello"
}

// for observing the change -> observe live data
viewModel.mutableLiveDataEditTextContent.observe(this, Observer {
    val isUserInputChangeNotDynamicallyChanged = binding.editText
        .getTag(R.id.editText_textTwoWay_isUserInputChangeNotDynamicallyChanged) as? Boolean
    val prefixMsg = when (isUserInputChangeNotDynamicallyChanged) {
        true -> {
            "User Change -> "
        }
        false -> {
            "Dynamic Change -> "
        }
        null -> {
            "UNKNOWN Change -> "
        }
    }
    val msg = prefixMsg + it.toStringOrEmpty()
    toast(msg) // extension fun for showing a Toast
    logError(msg) // to ensure invocation is done once isa.
})
```